# How can I load a texture in separate thread in cocos2d-x?

Tags: multithreading, cocos2d-x

I faced the need to use multi-threading to load an additional texture on-the-fly in order to reduce the memory footprint.

The example case is that I have 10 types of enemy to use in the a single level but the enemies will come out type by type. The context of "type by type" means one type of enemy comes out and the player kills all of its instances, then it's time to call in another type. The process goes like this until all types come out, then the level is complete.

You can see it's better to not initially load all enemy's texture at once in the starting time (it's pretty big 2048*2048 with lots of animation frames inside which I need to create them in time of creation for each type of enemy). I turn this to multi-thread to load an additional texture when I need it. But I knew that cocos2d-x is **not thread-safe**. I planned to use CCSpriteFrameCache class to load a texture from .plist + .png file then re-create animation there and finally create a CCSprite from it to represent a new type of enemy instance. If I don't use multi-thread, I might suffer from delay of lag that would occur of loading a large size of texture.

So how can I load a texture in separate thread in cocos2d-x following my goal above? Any idea to avoid thread-safe issue but still can accomplish my goal is also appreciated.

Note: I'm developing on iOS platform.

Answer (score 4):

I found that async-loading of image is already there inside cocos2d-x.
You can build a testing project of cocos2d-x and look into "Texture2DTest", then tap on the left arrow to see how async-loading look like.

I have taken a look inside the code.
You can use `addImageAsync` method of `CCtextureCache` to load additional texture on-the-fly without interfere or slow down other parts such as the current animation that is running. 
In fact, `addImageAsync` of `CCTextureCache` will load `CCTexture2D` object for you and return back to its callback method to receive. You have additional task to make use of it on your behalf.

Please note that `CCSpriteFrameCache` uses `CCTextureCache` to load frames. So this applies to it as well for my case to load spritesheet consisting of frames to be used in animation creation. But unfortunately async type of method is not provided for `CCSpriteFrameCache` class. You have to manually load texture object via `CCTextureCache` then plug it in

`void CCSpriteFrameCache::addSpriteFramesWithFile(const char *pszPlist, CCTexture2D *pobTexture)`

There's 2 file in testing project you can take a look at.

- Texture2dTest.cpp
- TextureCacheTest.cpp